# BizTalk XML to JSON Pipeline - Force JSON array even without a schema target namespace

Tags: json, xml, biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

Coming from this question: [Conversion of XML Schema to JSON array list in Biztalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204027/conversion-of-xml-schema-to-json-array-list-in-biztalk)

We have the same situation: Our XML needs to be converted to JSON and we have child objects which can occur one or multiple times which must always result in a JSON array.

The problem is that we are not able to set a target namespace because our schema is generated by SAP (IDoc).

Are there other options to do the serialization? I would like to avoid a custom implementation for JSON serialization.

Comment: Are you receiving a SAP message and trying to send it as JSON to another system?   Can you create an schema based on the SAP one but where you add a namespace and then map the SAP message to that?

Comment: Yes I've solved it this way. I've created a second schema including a target namespace and mapped the SAP message to it. The only "disadvantage" here is that I have another schema and map to maintain. Thanks for your inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an internal BizTalk schema with a target namespace and map the SAP payload to that.